node-thermal-printer Arabic language printing
i'm using node-thermal-printer package to print an arabic invoice, but it doesn't work properly although i changed the charSet to arabic ( characterSet: CharacterSet.WPC1256_ARABIC)
ipcMain.on('print-bill', async (event, billData) => {
    if (!printerName) {
      console.error('No printer selected')
      return
    }

    try {
      let printer = new ThermalPrinter({
        type: PrinterTypes.EPSON,
        interface: `tcp://192.168.192.168:9100`,
        characterSet: CharacterSet.WPC1256_ARABIC,
        removeSpecialCharacters: false,
        lineCharacter: '=',
        breakLine: BreakLine.WORD,
        options: {
          timeout: 5000
        }
      })
      printer.alignCenter()
      printer.print('مرحبا')
      printer.print('Hello, World!')

      printer.printBarcode('GS1-128', 74, {
        hriPos: 0,
        hriFont: 0,
        width: 3,
        height: 168
      })
      printer.printQR('QR CODE', {
        cellSize: 3,
        correction: 'M',
        model: 2
      })

      await printer.printImage(icon3)
      printer.cut()
      try {
        await printer.execute()
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error printing billll:', err)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error printing bill:', err)
    }
  })
}

every thing works fine until i add this printer.print('مرحبا')
i' expecting the printer to print arabic normally

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Note that "doesn't work properly" does not describe a problem: Is there an error message? (which one) - Does the printer print different symbols? Does it burst in flames?
